# Get the most recent and not null row

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, sql-null

I have the following table:

| id | timestamp | attribute-1 | attribute-2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8/12 |  | A |
| 1 | 8/13 | B |  |
| 2 | 8/12 |  | A |
| 2 | 8/13 | C | B |
| 2 | 8/14 | B |  |
| 3 | 8/12 | B |  |
| 3 | 8/14 | C | C |

And would like to create a new table with the most updated attributes for each id, which means the most recent row for each id as long as it has both att-1 and att-2, if it doesn't I want to take the att from a previous row. should be like that:

| id | attribute-1 | attribute-2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | B | A |
| 2 | B | B |
| 3 | C | C |

- The timestamp is a real psql timestamp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `FIRST_VALUE()` window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, 
       FIRST_VALUE(attribute1) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY attribute1 IS NULL, timestamp DESC) attribute1,
       FIRST_VALUE(attribute2) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY attribute2 IS NULL, timestamp DESC) attribute2
FROM tablename;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=9f9a11c0eb05a8ea4dee25bdb664fe95).

Answer (score 1):

I created a table with following data as per your input

```
CREATE TABLE data (
  "id" INTEGER,
  "timestamp" DATE,
  "attribute1" VARCHAR(1),
  "attribute2" VARCHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO data
  ("id", "timestamp", "attribute1", "attribute2")
VALUES
  ('1', '2021-08-12', null, 'A'),
  ('1', '2021-08-13', 'B', null),
  ('2', '2021-08-12', null, 'A'),
  ('2', '2021-08-13', 'C', 'B'),
  ('2', '2021-08-14', 'B', null),
  ('3', '2021-08-12', 'B', null),
  ('3', '2021-08-14', 'C', 'C');
```

I think you can achieve your result by aggregating data and picking the first result in that:

```
SELECT 
    id, MAX(timestamp) AS timestamp_max,
    (array_remove(array_agg(attribute1 ORDER BY timestamp DESC), NULL))[1] AS attribute1_agg,
    (array_remove(array_agg(attribute2 ORDER BY timestamp DESC), NULL))[1] AS attribute1_agg
FROM data
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

which gives this output:

| id | timestamp_max | attribute1_agg | attribute1_agg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-08-13T00:00:00.000Z | B | A |
| 2 | 2021-08-14T00:00:00.000Z | B | B |
| 3 | 2021-08-14T00:00:00.000Z | C | C |